# Can I test regular XMLHttpRequests with Angular's $httpBackend?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, file-upload, xmlhttprequest-level2

I have an AngularJS application, which needs file uploads, and as `$http` does not support the special features of `XMLHttpRequest.upload`, I have to perform the file upload using an XMLHttpRequest.

My question is: Can I use the `$httpBackend` to unit test the requests made via `new XMLHttpRequest()`?

I have some tests made, but at the moment `$httpBackend` is throwing errors. Without calling `$httpBackend.flush()` it complained about unsatisfied requests, but adding the `flush`, just caused an "No pending requests" error.

Extensive use of search engines didn't yield an answer for me, so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect no, but you could still unit test your code if you refactor it slightly:

- Create a small factory that returns a `new $window.XMLHttpRequest()`.
- Then in the services/controllers, instead of calling `new XMLHttpRequest()` directly, inject this factory when you need to make call to the upload()
- You can unit test the service/controllers by mocking up the factory and injecting it in before the test.
- You can even unit test the small factory by mocking up `$window` with an `XMLHttpRequest` constructor, and injecting that in before the test.